# How to run more than one instance of Windows Store app alongside eachother?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I am developing a Windows store app and would like to run more than one instance at the same time. When I try running one from VS and another from the built .exe I get the error:

"The application can only in the context of an app container."

Is there any way do what I want?

Comment: No. Multiple instances are not supported.

Comment: Might be best to explain WHY you want to do this, and their may be a better way.

Comment: app does comms over sockets - want to test on localhost instead of another machine